# Does my Macbook have Airdrop

Tags: macbook-pro, airdrop

I have a macbook pro 1226, does it have airdrop?

Answer (score 3):

Here are the following requirements for Airdrop from [Apple's Support Article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4783)

> - Software: OS X Lion or later installed.
>
> **Compatible Machines**
>
> > - MacBook Pro (Late 2008 or newer)*
> > - MacBook Air (Late 2010 or newer)
> > - MacBook (Late 2008 or newer)*
> > - iMac (Early 2009 or newer)
> > - Mac Mini (Mid 2010 or newer)
> > - Mac Pro (Early 2009 with AirPort Extreme card, or Mid 2010)